# php Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: php, class

Last line echo doesn`t work.
How can i refer to the id or nickname?
The error i receive is Call to a member function on a non-object in.
dsaojfj kjsaoj oisjao jpods jop djopa jpaos jdo jpoajsoj op pa poj opdjaojs pojap jposajop jopajojdopsajodjop jaop jpoj ojdojpsoaj ojod jopajsdodjaospjop d add details ....srr.

```
<?php
class  test{

    public $id;
    public $nickname;

    function __construct($id_, $nickname_) {
        $this->id = $id_;
        $this->nickname = $nickname_;
    }

    public function setId($id_){
       $this->id = $id_;
    }
    public function setNickname($nickname_){
       $this->nickname = $nickname_;
    }
    public function getId(){
       return $this->id;
    }
    public function getNickname(){
       return $this->nickname;
    }
}

class  InfoTest{

    public $tests = array();
    public $number;

    function __construct() {
       $this->number = 0;
    }

    public function addTest(test $test_){
        $this->number++;
        $this->tests[$number] = $test_;
    }

    public function numberTests(){
        return $this->number;
    }

}


$r = new test(1,2);
$cc = new InfoTest;
$cc->addTest($r);
echo $cc->tests[1]->getId();

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you forgot $this-> on the second use of number variable:

```
    $this->number++;
    $this->tests[$number] = $test_;
```

should be

```
    $this->number++;
    $this->tests[$this->number] = $test_;
```

Comment: i`m new to php and thought that this might not work $cc->tests[1]->getId(); but it does, thanks :]